# Remove stop words from a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

I have a hashmap consisting of keys as words ( strings) and values as their counts ( integer).

I have to remove stopwords  from the hashmap. Essentially , I have to do a hMap.remove("then") , hMpa.remove("where") for some 67 words. Is there any easier way of doing it ? Can I delete multiple keys from a hashmap in a single stroke.

Comment: No, add your words to a list and call remove for each of them in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `hMap.keySet().removeAll(the_stuff_you_want_to_remove)`

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29):

> The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations.

Comment: Is it like hMap.keySet().removeAll("then","where","apple" ) ?

Comment: @user2623946 You need to pass it a collection, which you can make up with your 67 terms.

Comment: @user2623946 No, remove all receives a collection as a parameter.

Comment: @user2623946 It's [removeAll(Collection<?>)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29). So if you have the list of items to remove in a Collection (like a List), just pass that.

Answer (score 2):

@user2623946
No, you must use a collection for it. 
Or something like that:

```
String[] arr = {"a","b","c"};
myMap.keySet().removeAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should help you out;

```
Map<String, Integer> ohm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("One");
al.add("Two");

ohm.put("One", 1);
ohm.put("Two", 2);
ohm.put("Three", 3);

ohm.keySet().removeAll(al);
System.out.println(ohm);  // Output: [Three = 3]
```

Hope this helps.